# My PC with Linux operating system always freezes just after 5 to 10 minutes I start the computer

Tags: linux, freeze

When I start my PC, just after 5 to 10 minutes computer freezes completely and nothing works like mouse and keyboard, this happens every time I start my computer.

Previously computer was getting freeze once in a week like that
but now it happens every time I boot my computer

and previously my computer was also getting a automatic reboot while its working normally even this used to happen once a week like that,

but that doesn't happen now, now it just gets freeze just after the 5 minutes I boot the computer,
all the fans and system works normally but not at all any response.

Also my hard disk light stops working when it gets freeze, I even have a new SSD but even the same goes with that.

It's very frustrating please help.

it's low end PC it has

- Core2duo processor,
- 4 GB of DDR2 ram
- 1 GB Nvidia graphics card (Nvidia 1800 GS)

with

- Zorin os lite in hard drive and
- Zorien os core version in SSD
  I have tried with both of them same problem.

And I think I have not installed the proprietary drivers And the operating system version is Zorien 16 latest version of zorin.

(Also my hard disk light stops working when it gets freeze, I even have a new SSD but even the same goes with that)

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors.

Comment: I have a SSD and a hard drive I have checked with both of them same problem. I have got a new SSD a week ago.

Comment: If so we need the full hardware specifications and the Linux distro release/version to start thinking about it. The most important info is about your graphics card and whether or not you installed proprietary drivers.